# How can I analyze multiple s3 inventories using athena?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I want to analyze multiple s3 inventories using athena.

I have multiple s3 inventories for multiple buckets.

I want to load all inventories into one table.

Could you give any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files have the same schemas I suggest to use table partitioning functionality. You can create partitioned table and then add each bucket as partition.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html

You can use also Glue Crawler:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-best-practices.html#schema-crawlers-data-sources